# Population arrays inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am having the following parent component.

```
class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const options = ['Thing one', 'Thing two', 'Thing three']

        return (
            <div>
                <Options options={options} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see I am defining a component inside the render function called Options. And in that component, I am passing an argument called options. My goal to populate that options array inside the Options component. So this is what I am doing.

```
class Options extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.options)
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.options.forEach((o) => {
                        return <p key={this.props.options}>{o}</p>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

However, I see nothing in the output. Why is that? What did I do wrong?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: Do you want to create one `Option` for every entry in the array? Map it in the parent component then. Otherwise, outputting the entries wrapping each in a paragraph use `map` in the Option component rather than `forEach`.

Comment: forEach just iterates over your array, as Drew mentioned, you need to use map if you need to transform your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `map` the options to return an array of JSX elements, `forEach` doesn't return an array. Remember the react keys need to be unique.

[Lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
class Options extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.options)
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.options.map((o) => {
            return <p key={o}>{o}</p> // <-- keys should be unique in dataset
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map instead of forEach because forEach does not return an array

```
class Options extends Component {

        const renderData = this.props.options.map(function(data, idx) {
            return <p key={idx}>{data}</p>
        });

        return (
            <div>  
                {renderData}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```